# How do I move 'Add to Cart', price, and 'Product Options' to top of page

Tags: html, e-commerce, cart

Here is what I am attempting to do:

[image]

I would like to move the add to cart button, along with all other price and variation options to sit beside the product image, with the product information to begin below the pricing information.

I think these are the relevant parts of the code, but I'm still a beginner so can't be sure.

```
<?php if((get_option('hide_addtocart_button') == 0) &&  (get_option('addtocart_or_buynow') !='1')) : ?>
                            <?php if(wpsc_product_has_stock()) : ?>
                                <div class="wpsc_buy_button_container">
                                        <?php if(wpsc_product_external_link(wpsc_the_product_id()) != '') : ?>
                                        <?php $action = wpsc_product_external_link( wpsc_the_product_id() ); ?>
                                        <input class="wpsc_buy_button" type="submit" value="<?php echo wpsc_product_external_link_text( wpsc_the_product_id(), __( 'Buy Now', 'wpsc' ) ); ?>" onclick="return gotoexternallink('<?php echo $action; ?>', '<?php echo wpsc_product_external_link_target( wpsc_the_product_id() ); ?>')">
                                        <?php else: ?>
                                    <input type="submit" value="<?php _e('Add To Cart', 'wpsc'); ?>" name="Buy" class="wpsc_buy_button" id="product_<?php echo wpsc_the_product_id(); ?>_submit_button"/>
```

and

```
<?php if((get_option('hide_addtocart_button') == 0) &&  (get_option('addtocart_or_buynow') !='1')) : ?>
                            <?php if(wpsc_product_has_stock()) : ?>
                                <div class="wpsc_buy_button_container">
                                        <?php if(wpsc_product_external_link(wpsc_the_product_id()) != '') : ?>
                                        <?php $action = wpsc_product_external_link( wpsc_the_product_id() ); ?>
                                        <input class="wpsc_buy_button" type="submit" value="<?php echo wpsc_product_external_link_text( wpsc_the_product_id(), __( 'Buy Now', 'wpsc' ) ); ?>" onclick="return gotoexternallink('<?php echo $action; ?>', '<?php echo wpsc_product_external_link_target( wpsc_the_product_id() ); ?>')">
                                        <?php else: ?>
                                    <input type="submit" value="<?php _e('Add To Cart', 'wpsc'); ?>" name="Buy" class="wpsc_buy_button" id="product_<?php echo wpsc_the_product_id(); ?>_submit_button"/>
```

EDIT: Sorry mproncace I tried following your instructions but I'm just not getting it. Can it be done in the CSS?

```
`/*single product page*/
.imagecol,.productcol {float:left;}
.productcol {vertical-align:top; width:100%; margin:0 0 0 5px;}
.single_product_display h1  {line-height:20px; margin:0 0 17px;}
.single_product_display form  {margin:20px 0 0;}
.single_product_display label {float:left; margin:0 10px 0 0;}
.single_product_display input[type="text"] {width:20px; margin:0 0 0 10px; border:1px         solid #CCC;}
.pricedisplay {font-size:18px; font-weight:normal;}
.single_product_display form  {float:left;}
.single_product_display .wpsc_buy_button_container  {float:left; text-align:left     !important;}
.single_product_display .wpsc_buy_button {background:#CB8700; border:0; padding:5px !important; color:#FFF; cursor:pointer;}
```

Comment: For future reference you can use the image tag to embed images. What you want to do requires editing the entire HTML of the page, not just the relevant PHP code. This will require more than the snippets you have provided.

Comment: Thanks for that Christian, I couldn't embed images as I don't have 10 reputation yet, I appreciate you letting people see it.

I've pasted the entire code for my wpsc-single_product.php at http://codetidy.com/5369/ if anyone is willing to help me out. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's the format you would want for this:

```
<div id="container">
    <div id="maincolumn" style="float:left">
        <div id="itempreview" style="float:left">
            <!-- HTML/PHP goes here -->
        </div>
        <div id="itemsidebar" style="float:right">
            <div id="addtocart">
                <!-- HTML/PHP goes here -->
            </div>
            <div id="itemdescription">
                <!-- HTML/PHP goes here -->
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div id="items" style="float:right">
        <!-- HTML/PHP goes here -->
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Sorry it's taken me so long to reply but I didn't understand where exactly to put the "style" coding, but, using my own div ids I've and your advice I've managed to do what I wanted. Your help was invaluable, thank you!

Comment: EDIT: Hmm, correction: I've been working in Firefox, and just noticed that the problem still isn't resolved in Chrome and IE. The Product Options refuse to move from below the image to the right of the image. How is that even possible!? Any ideas?

Comment: @Reibusu I'm a bit confused as to Chrome not working, as its HTML parser is similar to that of Firefox, but with IE, I suppose it's a given that it won't immediately work. You may want to try adding the style information "margin-left: auto" to the "itemdescription" div (the div you want to move to the right). I've never used that for anything other than centering a div, so it may prove ineffective, but it's worth a shot.

Comment: No joy, I've tried every display, position, float and margin combination I can think of.

Comment: @Reibusu Well then, I've got nothing. Design and CSS aren't my strong points; I was just offering up what I knew. Sorry I can't help more, but I wish you luck in getting the styling to work.

Comment: I've found it, adding `{ width:390px; } .product_description { clear: both; }` after every instance of `form.product_form` in the CSS has done it for me. Thanks for your help!